# PowerShell Script in TFS Build not uploading to Azure

Tags: azure, build

After searching on Google, I've managed to put together a powershell script based on [this site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/#step4) to upload my azure project. When I try to add it to TFS build process using the steps on the same site I get the following output:

[image]
My build says it's been running for 7 hours and if I login to windows azure there is no mention of the package. I have run it numerous other times since but not for as long, even after 10 minutes it still hasn't changed anything on the Azure dashboard.

If I run the same command from a command prompt on the build server then it runs and uploads the staging environment and it takes about 8-10 minutes to complete. Is there anything special I have to do to get it to run from TFS Build, or is there a way that I can get more meaningful output?

Comment: I’m not very familiar with TFS. But this link may help: http://blog.slalom.com/2011/08/19/building-and-deploying-windows-azure-projects-using-msbuild-and-tfs-2010/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. The default.publishsettings didn't have permission for the build service to read it. Added full permissions for the service and it now works.